# Missing methods in Selenium 3.2.0

Tags: selenium, window, registry

while in earlier Releases of Selenium I used to use methods like
WindowsUtils.readIntRegistryValue(location); and
WindowsUtils.writeIntRegistryValue(location, 0);
to read and write to Window Registry.
As I transit from earlier releases to new Release 3.2; to my surprise these methods were missing in new release of selenium.
Kindly mention the alternate that has replaced those methods or the strategy to perform tasks such as reading and writing to Window Registery in selenium 3.1 and Selenium 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/717918fb1aba6f24d0ae9f7114a6228430b39c62) presumably because it wasn't being used, perhaps the devs didn't think this was being used outside of `selenium` internals.

Honestly, I wouldn't use `selenium` to read from windows registries.

That being said, you can go to that commit I linked and copy the code you need into your own project if you want, just beware that it might need some updating when windows updates.

Alternatively, you can look somewhere outside of `selenium` to work with windows registries.

Best of luck!